# How to rotate outer div not inner content

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

How to fit an image inside a div and this div is rotated at 45deg?

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Comment: please post your html and css code

Comment: It would be useful if you would provide a bit of code but the simples thing I would think of is to rotate the content 45° into the opposite direction...

Comment: Please take a look at what I'm doing and whats wrong with my code I just want to fit image inside the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/u4mcr0kd/2/

Answer (score 4):

Add `scale` value in transform style for `img` like this:

```css
.profile-photo { width: 210px; height: 210px; position: relative; left: 43px; top: 50px; border: 8px solid #000; border-radius: 60px; transform: rotate(45deg); overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; background: #34983e;padding:0 }

.profile-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.21)
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-photo"> 
  <img alt="Profile photo" src="http://www.michiganurology.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/reddy.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://via.placeholder.com/500/E5E8EC/4B89DA?text=error+image';">
</div>
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks, man. 
You saved my day it works for me.
I am accepting your answer but can't showing as green I don't know why

Comment: You're welcome friend. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score -1):

use below code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="index.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div
    {
        width: 500px;
        background: lightblue;
        transform: rotate(40deg);
    }
```

[W3schools transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_transform.asp)